# Trailing slash problem

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I have magento running in my localhost. But a trailing slash is not getting added to the URL. This causes `javascript` and `css` files to be not found and so the entire magento application is not running properly. Below are the URLs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://localhostskin/adminhtml/default/default/print.css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://localhostskin/adminhtml/default/default/menu.css" media="screen, projection">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhostjs/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhostjs/prototype/window.js"></script>
```

which are supposed to be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://localhost/skin/adminhtml/default/default/print.css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://localhost/skin/adminhtml/default/default/menu.css" media="screen, projection">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost/js/prototype/window.js"></script>
```

Comment: show your coding file to get more info, where you have declared js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your Base URL to `http(s)://localhost/` in `System >> Configuration >> Web >>`

Since you are not able to load the admin itself, run below queries in your database:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET `value` = 'http://localhost/' WHERE `path` LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET `value` = 'https://localhost/' WHERE `path` LIKE 'web/secure/base_url'
```

**Make sure you add necessary conditions `scope` and `scope_id` if you are running on multiwebsite**

Also don't forget to flush your cache.

Comment: Yes, the URLs were like [http://localhost](http://localhost) and [https://localhost](https://localhost) before. Now I updated them to [http://localhost/](http://localhost/) and [https://localhost/](https://localhost/) in the core_config_data table. But still the slashes are missing after refreshing the home page. Do I need to run any indexing commands anywhere?

Comment: No need to reindex. Just flush your magento cache (`rm -r var/cache/*`). Also check whether your media/skin/js urls in core_config_data have trailing slashes

Comment: Yes i flushed the cache. Now its working fine. Thanks for your help!!.

Comment: Please tick this as answer then, will be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

Check the base url in system->configuration or in the database in the `core_config_data` table.
It should end with a slash (`http://localhost/`).
And a small tip, don't use localhost as a base url. It may not work on certain cases. Use `127.0.0.1` instead.